# Why can't this selenium script register for this site?

Tags: python, selenium

Everytime I run this, the Footlocker site returns a weird error saying they blocked the register attempt, I think this has to do with cookies or headers and I'm fairly new to coding so i don't understand whats going on, if anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

**Script:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests

email = "email"
passw = "gsd"
month = "January"
day = "16"
year = "1998"
fname = "gjgh"
lname = "ghjgh"
st1 = "john st"
st2 = "2nd floor"
zipi = "11345"
city = "chinatown"
state = "New York"
phone = "5555555555"





def generateAccount():

    url = "https://www.footaction.com/account/default.cfm?action=accountCreate"
    path = r"C:\Users\Cihad Gul\Desktop\chrome driver\chromedriver.exe"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    browser.get(url)
    EMAIL = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="email"]""").send_keys(email)
    PASS = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="password"]""").send_keys(passw)
    CPASS = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="confirmPassword"]""").send_keys(passw)
    MONTH = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBirthdateMM"]""").send_keys(month)
    DAY = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBirthdateDD"]""").send_keys(day)
    YEAR = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBirthdateYY"]""").send_keys(year)
    FNAME = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="billFirstName"]""").send_keys(fname)
    LNAME = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="billLastName"]""").send_keys(lname)
    ST1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="billStreet1"]""").send_keys(st1)
    ST2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="billStreet2"]""").send_keys(st2)
    ZIP = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="bill_uszip"]""").send_keys(zipi)
    CITY = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="billCity"]""").send_keys(city)
    STATE = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="billstate"]""").send_keys(state)
    PHONE = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="billPhone"]""").send_keys(phone)
    CHECKBOX = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="oneContact"]""").click()
    #SUBMIT = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="nextButton"]/button""").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    SUBMIT = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#nextButton").click()
generateAccount()
```

Comment: your email has the wrong type)  try "test@test.com" or similar

Comment: in any way try to do all same actions manually. If you can do it manually - you would be able to do this with code

Comment: i used one like that, I tried manually and it brings me to a page saying it was blocked